# Lowering document.domain

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

What am I doing wrong? According to [specs](http://blogs.msdn.com/nevermet/archive/2009/07/14/document-domain-can-cause-invalid-argument-error-in-ie8.aspx) lowering domain with JavaScript should be possible in IE8 and IE7 but my code only works in Firefox and throws an Argument Exception in IE.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<body onload="alert(document.domain); try { document.domain = 'if.se' } catch(e) { alert(e); }; alert(document.domain);">
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit**

The problem might be because of two letter domain. I tested with three letter domain (iff.se) and it worked, but a two letter domain failed (if.se)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably getting caught inside a sanity check to make sure you don't try and set document.domain to co.uk or something silly like that.

Comment: this woureally sad. Maybe you have and idea where I can get documentation regarding this issue?